# Flask file Upload unable to get form data

Tags: python, angular, flask

Angular 4
Flask 1.0.2

Hi all

I am trying to upload a file from Angular by populating a new FormData() object and posting it.  It appears to be posting ok, but I can't get the values from the post from within Flask.

I call this from a button click event:

```
UploadFile() : void{
    let formModel = new FormData()
    formModel.set('fileName', this.fileName);
    formModel.set('fileData', this.form.get('fileData').value);

    this.filesProvider.UploadFile(formModel)
      .subscribe(res => {
      this.UploadFileProcessed(res, true);
    }
    , (err) => {
      this.UploadFileProcessed(err, false);
    }
);
```

...which calls a provider...

```
UploadFile(formData: FormData) : Observable<Response> {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Content-Type', null);
    headers.set('Accept', "multipart/form-data");
    headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(access_token + ":"));
    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers })

    return this.http
    .post(this.globalVarsProvider.apiUrl + "member/uploadFile", formData, requestOptions)
    .map((response: Response) => response);
}
```

On the Flask API end I have this:

```
@app.route('/api/member/uploadFile', methods=['POST'])
@auth.login_required
def uploadFile(): 
    print request.form.get('key1')
    return "ok"
```

Running this outputs "None" in the Flask dev server terminal.

If I do `print request.get_data()` I see all the post data (including the crazy image data stuff).

In Chrome the request looks like this:

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong please and how I get the data from within Flask?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did two things wrong:

- You set the `Content-Type` header to `null`, so it is left empty. Now Angular can't tell the server how to split out the different parts of a `multipart/form` request.
- You are not accessing the correct fields on the server side.

You should **not** set the `Content-Type` header at all, so remove the `headers.set('Content-Type', null)` call. Angular 4 then [sets the header for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46690502/100297), to `multipart/form-data` and will include the boundary value (the string betwen fields in the request body) in that header.

Your Flask code is trying to access a non-existing field. Your frontend code posts two fields:

```js
formModel.set('fileName', this.fileName);
formModel.set('fileData', this.form.get('fileData').value);
```

and your screenshots confirm that `fileName` and `fileData` parts are indeed posted. But your Flask code tries to access `key1`:

```
print request.form.get('key1')
```

There is no such key, so the `.get()` method returns the default value, `None`, instead.

For file uploads, you really want to use [`request.files` attribute](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.files); see the documentation for that attribute and for the [`requests.form` attribute](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.form):

> **`form`**: A `MultiDict` with the parsed form data from `POST` or `PUT` requests. Please keep in mind that file uploads will not end up here, but instead in the `files` attribute.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **`files`**: A `MultiDict` with files uploaded as part of a `POST` or `PUT` request. Each file is stored as `FileStorage` object. It basically behaves like a standard file object you know from Python, with the difference that it also has a `save()` function that can store the file on the filesystem.

So use `request.form['fileName']` and `request.files['fileData']` to access the two fields.

Also see the [*Uploading Files* pattern documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/fileuploads/).

As a side note: You should not set the `Accept` header. The `Accept` header is there for a client (such as your browser) to tell the server what kind of *responses* are acceptable. `Accept: multipart/form` tells the server that you want it to respond with a `multipart/form` response. It says nothing about the content of the *request itself*. If you got your example from a comment to [this blog post (a top Google hit for "angular 4 form-data upload")](https://nehalist.io/uploading-files-in-angular2/), then that commenter has mislead you with non-working code. I've added a comment there to at least help future visitors avoid that error.

Comment: Thank you, this completely sorted it for me.  Greatly appreciated.  Thank you also for the clear explanation.  It was the [article you mentioned](https://nehalist.io/uploading-files-in-angular2/) that I had followed.

Comment: [https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/][1] is a Flask plugin to simplify File Uploads.
  [1]: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/