# 413 even for small files flask

Tags: python, flask, post

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1000 * 1000


ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = [".pdf", ".PDF"]


def allowed_file(filename):
    return "." in filename and filename.rsplit(".", 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route("/upload-pdf", methods=["POST"])
def upload_pdf():
    # check if the post request has the file partx
    if "file" not in request.files:
        resp = jsonify({"message": "No file part in the request"})
        resp.status_code = 400
        return resp
    file = request.files["file"]
    if file.filename == "":
        resp = jsonify({"message": "No file selected for uploading"})
        resp.status_code = 400
        return resp
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        print(type(filename))
        # file.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename))
        resp = jsonify({"message": "File successfully uploaded"})
        resp.status_code = 201
    else:
        resp = jsonify(
            {"message": "Allowed file types are pdf"}
        )
        resp.status_code = 400
    return resp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is my code. BUt when I run `python app.py` and the curl command `curl -d @it_return_2020_21.pdf http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload-pdf`. I get `<title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>`. The file I am trying to upload is 275 kb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> curl -d @it_return_2020_21.pdf http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload-pdf
> ```

When you use `-d` or `--data` with `curl`, it sends the data as the request body with the content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is not appropriate for file uploads.

In contrast, Flask's `request.files` looks for files sent as multipart/form-data (as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51765724/6309)).
You should use the `-F` or `--form` option in `curl` to send the file correctly:

```bash
curl -F "file=@it_return_2020_21.pdf" http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload-pdf
```

This command should correctly upload your file to the Flask application:

- The `-F` option tells curl to POST data using the `Content-Type multipart/form-data`, which is the correct type for file uploads.
- The `file=@it_return_2020_21.pdf` part tells curl to include a form field named file, and to read the content from the file `it_return_2020_21.pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

A careful reading of the documentation for [`request.files`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Request.files) shows that this only works with multipart/form-data content. See the documentation excerpt below (emphasis mine)

> property files: ImmutableMultiDict[str, FileStorage]
>
> MultiDict object containing all uploaded files. Each key in files is the name from the . Each value in files is a Werkzeug FileStorage object.
>
> It basically behaves like a standard file object you know from Python, with the difference that it also has a save() function that can store the file on the filesystem.
>
> **Note that files will only contain data if the request method was POST, PUT or PATCH and the  that posted to the request had enctype="multipart/form-data". It will be empty otherwise.**
>
> See the MultiDict / FileStorage documentation for more details about the used data structure.

Using `curl -d @filename URI` as you indicated above sends a request with content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Add a bunch of verbose flags to curl to see this (`-vvv` should do the trick).

If, instead, you use the form data flag `-F it_return_2020_21.pdf=@it_return_2020_21.pdf`, you should see your expected results.

I'm able to reproduce the error with some dummy data:

```bash
$ flask run
```

```bash
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=file.pdf bytes=1024 count=2
$ curl -d @file.pdf http://localhost:5000/upload-pdf
$ # observe the error
$ curl -F file.pdf=@file.pdf http://localhost:5000/upload-pdf
$ # observe a 400 instead, because my data is malformed (expected, it's random bytes!)
```

Comment: Looks like you could include a CONTENT_LENGTH header with your request to get around this, or just change your default configuration.