# what is the better way of upload image in angular project?

Tags: angular, image, file-upload, npm-install

I have a webcam so i need to capture a ID card and uploading the image for my angular project. anybody suggest me the simple npm library for do it.

Comment: [ng file upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-file-upload)

Comment: you basically don't need a library too, just sending file  like regular upload will do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45160884/file-upload-and-download-in-angular-4-typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use formData upload like the method below:

```
 public upload(file: any): Observable<any> {

    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    const params = new HttpParams();

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    if (file) {
      formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    }
    return this.http.put(this.Url, formData, { headers, params })
        .pipe(map((response: any) => {
          return response;
     }));
}
```